# PyInstaller/PyQt4: System tray icon is not loading (blank)

Tags: python, icons, pyqt4, pyinstaller, trayicon

I'm trying to build my app with PyInstaller. When I build it, the system tray icon is blank. It's there, but it's blank.

(I'm on windows)

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

It's loading the icon from "logo.gif" in the script code itself. I'm suspecting the problem is that the icon is not bundled into the exe properly. (I'm using the one-exe option).

Here's the command I use to build it:

```
pyinstaller twitchwatch.py -w -F
```

Comment: Question, but the icon is included in resources and converted with pyuic???